# RECENT Java References?

Tags: java, reference

I'e been programming Java forever, but have been away from it for a while.  Can anyone recommend a really good Java reference, where "really good" is defined by "Good coverage of the language, detailed coverage of recent extensions, and written for the technical reader (not a "for Dummies" sort of book)"?

Comment: Did you ever find a good book that was higher level? Especially stuff that's newer in version 6.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As well as references saying what has changed in the languages (which other answers already cover better than I could) I can't recommend highly enough the [Second edition of Effective Java by Joshua Bloch](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683) - which explains the most effective ways of using the language.

Comment: This is easily the best Java book I've ever read, and it's also one of the shortest.

Comment: Recommendations for learning resources [are off-topic for stackoverflow.com Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). However, this information [could be ok as part of a tag wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214338/997587).

Answer (score 4):

For anything to do with concurrency, get [Java Concurrency In Practice](http://www.javaconcurrencyinpractice.com/).

As well as helping you avoid most of the many nasty pitfalls awaiting you, it gives a very good treatment of the new [java.util.concurrent](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-frame.html) API memebers for Java 5 and 6.

Answer (score 2):

Bruce Eckel's [Thinking in Java 4th Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131872486)

Answer (score 0):

i've always liked cay horstmann's books: http://www.horstmann.com/corejava.html. these are 8'th editions. and there is gosling's http://java.sun.com/docs/books/javaprog/. haven't seen anything for 1.6 yet.

Comment: I believe it's "Cay", not "Cat" -- He was a professor of mine back  when I was a freshman for intro to programming :)